# Android saved-instance-state bundle?

Tags: android, android-activity, bundle

My question is very basic i was wondering if everything such as int, strings, and other values have to be static in order to save it into the "saved-instance-state" bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Bundle stores data by value. So you are basically copying your data into the bundle, this is to say that your variables have nothing to do with the data stored in the bundle.

Basically the bundle is a map of key value pairs. You can save whatever you want and then restore it.

That is why you can only use primitives and parcelables(which basically translates the object into a primitive map).